# Extract an array from an inner array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP. But I want to extract each item of the array and put it in the outside array like this:

```
[PordersProduct] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 300001300
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [name] => RELLENO CARNE P/ EMPANADA X KG
                )

            [requested] => 2.500
            [formula_quantity] => 0
            [cep_quantity] => 35.723
            [wr_semi_finished_quantity] => 0
            [in_execution_quantity] => 7488.131
            [wr_total_semi_finished_quantity] => 7523.854
            [to_produced_orders_quantity] => 0
        )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 300002841
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [name] => DISCO PARA EMPANDAS  DE  85 GRS POR UNIDAD
                )

            [requested] => 50
            [formula_quantity] => 0
            [cep_quantity] => 0
            [wr_semi_finished_quantity] => 0
            [in_execution_quantity] => 7925
            [wr_total_semi_finished_quantity] => 7925
            [to_produced_orders_quantity] => 0
        )

    )

)
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
[PordersProduct] => Array
(
[0] => Array
    (

        [product_id] => 300001300
        [Product] => Array
            (
                [name] => RELLENO CARNE P/ EMPANADA X KG
            )

        [requested] => 2.500
        [formula_quantity] => 0
        [cep_quantity] => 35.723
        [wr_semi_finished_quantity] => 0
        [in_execution_quantity] => 7488.131
        [wr_total_semi_finished_quantity] => 7523.854
        [to_produced_orders_quantity] => 0

    )

[1] => Array
    (

        [product_id] => 300002841
        [Product] => Array
            (
                [name] => DISCO PARA EMPANDAS  DE  85 GRS POR UNIDAD
            )

        [requested] => 50
        [formula_quantity] => 0
        [cep_quantity] => 0
        [wr_semi_finished_quantity] => 0
        [in_execution_quantity] => 7925
        [wr_total_semi_finished_quantity] => 7925
        [to_produced_orders_quantity] => 0

    )

)
```

How Can I do that??

I have tried this:

```
grouped_data_porders2 = array(); // other array
    foreach ($grouped_data_porders['PordersProduct'] as $key => $item) {
                $grouped_data_porders2['PordersProduct'][] = $item[$key];
            }
            $grouped_data_porders['PordersProduct'] = $grouped_data_porders2['PordersProduct'];
```

But it does not work, can you help me please.

Thanks

Comment: your keys don't match, e.g. `[0] -> [1]` and `[1] -> [0]`, and you're modifying the parent array while iterating it, which isn't generally a good idea.

Comment: grouped_data_porders2 this is another array, the original is grouped_data_porders without the 2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge PHP Arrays into Simple Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308665/merge-php-arrays-into-simple-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `foreach` to iterate over the array, then again to iterate over the inner array to create a new (final) array:

```
$PordersProduct = [];// <-- your array

foreach ($PordersProduct as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $block) {
        $final[] = $block;
    }
}

var_dump($final);
```

Comment: @phpmeh if you look at OP's expected output, key association is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function with the [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to flatten the external level of the array

```
$result=array_reduce($arr,'array_merge',array());
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to loop twice through your array

```
$new_data = [];
foreach ($data as $k1 => $v1){
   foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2){
     $new_data[$k1] = $v2; 
   }
}
print_r($new_data); // check the output.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$data = [];
$newdata = [];
foreach($data as $item){
    $newdata[] = $item[0];
}
```

**Update:** also checkout @uri-goren's answer. It's the same concept but shorter.

**Update 2:** @uri-goren seems to have changed his answer. It was something like this:

```
$newdata = array_map(function($item){
        return $item[0];
    }, $data);
```

This is using PHP's [array_map](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp) function which iterates through the array and sends each value to a custom function and returns a new array with the values given by the function. It expects the name of a function or an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and one or more arrays.